# Run time error 91 - IE Object

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

The code works correctly but when I try to close IE I get the following error:

> "Run Time Error 91"

```
Dim IE As Object
Dim shellWins As New ShellWindows
Dim IE_URL As String
Dim Row As Integer

Row = 2

For Each IE In shellWins
    IE_URL = IE.LocationURL
    If IE_URL <> vbNullString Then
        Sheet1.Range("A" & Row) = IE_URL
        row = Row + 1
    End If
Next

Set shellWins = Nothing
Set IE = Nothing

IE.quit
```

NEW CODE:

```
Dim shellWins As New ShellWindows
Dim objIE As Object
Dim objIE_TabURL As String
Dim Rowcount As Long

Rowcount = 2

With objIE

    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

        For Each objIE In shellWins

        objIE_TabURL = objIE.LocationURL

            If objIE_TabURL <> vbNullString And InStr(objIE_TabURL,     
            "file://") = 0 Then

                Rowcount = Rowcount + 1
                sht2.Range("A" & Rowcount) = objIE_TabURL

            End If

        Next

    objIE.Quit

End With
```

END NEW CODE

I try to read the url from tabs open in a IE session to export it in a sheet.

I'm so sorry but i'm a newbie in a VBA :-(

Comment: You `Set IE = Nothing` before you quit, so you killed the `IE` object and after that you cannot access it anymore. Quit before setting `IE = Nothing` should work.

Comment: @Peh actually, `IE` isn't even set to an instance of Internet Explorer outside of the loop so that won't work.

Comment: @MacroMan you are totally right. Only saw the obvious issue in the end that matched to the error message.

Comment: i try but doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IE` isn't actually set to an instance of Internet Explorer at any point, you're using it as an object variant in a loop. Once the loop finishes, the variables becomes out of scope, and therefore cannot be accessed any more in the way you would like.

If you want to close IE after retrieving the URL, change your code to:

```
For Each IE In shellWins
    IE_URL = IE.LocationURL
    If IE_URL <> vbNullString Then
        Sheet1.Range("A" & Row) = IE_URL
        row = Row + 1
        IE.Quit '// Close IE here, while the variable is still in scope
    End If
Next
```

Note there is no need to `Set IE = Nothing` at the end of your routine as VBA automatically manages memory for you.

Comment: i try to use your code but 1 tab (and ie) remains open why?

Comment: The logic of your code means it will only close the instance of IE where the URL matches the URL you are looking for. You will have to re-arrange the logic if you want to close all IE windows.

Comment: suggestions? :-)

Comment: e.g. Move the `IE.Quit` statement outside of the `If` block - but then you need to do an additional check to ensure it really is an IE object before calling the `.Quit` method on it.

Comment: I'm not going to write the code for you as you won't learn anything from that. Instead - I give you the gift of [being able to debug your own code properly](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx). You need to step through your code to see what it's doing and change the logic accordingly.

Comment: Show us - update your original post and add the extra code that you've tried (show it separately please)

Comment: I solved using this code:

    Dim objIE As Object
    Dim shellWins As New ShellWindows
    Dim objIE_TabURL As String
    Dim count As Integer

    count = shellWins.count

    Do While count >= 1

        For Each objIE In shellWins
    
            objIE.Quit
    
        Next
    
    count = count - 1
    
    Loop